# Record delimiter in NACHA file format?

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

I have built an application to generate NACHA files for a client. It appears to do everything correctly, except that on attempting to upload the output to the ACH system the files are rejected. As far as I have been able to isolate the problem, it seems to have to do with the record delimiter expected by the NACHA format.

The application extracts data from several Excel spreadsheets and outputs a .txt file in NACHA format. Due to client requirements it is written in VBA (although VB.NET could be an alternative option).

The output follows all documented formatting requirements, but the bank's system responds with error messages indicating incorrect record length. However, we tried typing an exact duplicate of the output into Notepad by hand, which was accepted by the bank's system (!)

The output is generated via the TextStream method. Here is an abbreviated example of my original code:

```
Dim fso As Object
Dim stream As Object

'Create output file
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.fileexists(SavePath) Then Kill SavePath
Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile(SavePath, False, True)

'Insert file header
FileHeader = Get_1_Record
stream.WriteLine FileHeader
```

... where Get_1_Record is a subfunction that assembles a text string containing this particular record.

WriteLine automatically inserts a Line Feed character (ASCII code 10) at the end of the record, which seems to be incorrect. When the bank's tech support told me they had successfully uploaded a duplicate of the file, typed by hand, I thought the answer would be to substitute a Carriage Return instead (ASCII code 13). They must have used the "Enter" key to end each record, which as far as I know inserts a CR. So in place of the last line above I tried this:

```
stream.Write FileHeader
stream.Write Chr(13)
```

But this time the bank's system saw the entire file as being on a single line.

I have looked at code examples in other languages, e.g. js, but they all seem to be applying implicit record delimiters, similar to the WriteLine method used here, so I can't see how individual records are constructed.

I am at a loss here, and frankly out of my depth. Is anyone able to offer some insight on this? Am I barking up the wrong tree by focusing on the record delimiter?

Comment: I suspect the bank's system is expecting a carriage return Chr(13) followed by a line feed Chr(10). In VB.Net and VBA that would be `vbCrLf` (or `vbCr & vbLf`).

Comment: If you need an enter, you should use vbcrlf instead of chr(13) ?

Comment: Sounds like that might do it. I will test and report back here. Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: @BDra which bank are you with? I would like to avoid using any financial institution that uses Excel as a development platform! http://www.eusprig.org/horror-stories.htm

Comment: A 'hard return' or <enter> is two characters; a 13 followed by a 10. VB uses vbCRLF not vbCR or vbLF. A 'soft return' or line feed is just a 10 without the 13 hence vbLF.

Comment: Ditch Notepad, get Notepad++; with it you will be able to see non-printable characters `CR` and `LF`.

Comment: @Sam: Ha! I am developing this for a university whose admin staff uses Excel, but I am communicating with their bank to get it to work.

Comment: @Mathieu: Really good suggestion, thank you; I will check it out.

Comment: You are using the [FileSystemObject object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/filesystemobject-object)'s [CreateTextFile method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtextfile-method) that returns a [TextStream object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/textstream-object).  Use that object's [WriteBlankLines method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/writeblanklines-method) to append the new-line.

Comment: @BDra if it's solved please let us know and tagg the question as resolved by checking the answer.

Comment: @JustGreat: Thank you for following up. My sense is that the issue is resolved, but I am waiting for final confirmation from my client. I'm not in position to test it myself, since a live test involves ACH payment processing. They have to export payment data from their accounting system, run it through my application, and then submit it to their bank. As soon as I get confirmation that it worked, I will return here and tag the question as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we tried typing an exact duplicate of the output into Notepad by hand, which was accepted by the bank's system (!)

This is normal, because notepad doesn't show delimiters like line breaks etc...The problem may be that the bank is seeing the chr(13), but is expecting a chr(13) & chr(10) which is technically doesn't have the same size even if visualy on notepad you see them the same. 
if you try to replace the chr(13) by chr(13) & chr(10) and chr(10) it should work

so try :

```
stream.Write vbcrlf
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response(s). I had hoped to see a live ACH batch payment go through as official confirmation that the problem is resolved, but my clients are taking their sweet time on testing it. I did, however, get feedback from the bank's tech support indicating that the file formatted with vbCrLf triggers no errors in their internal verification software. On that basis I have gone ahead and awarded you the laurels -- thanks again.